# Programmatically check a checkbox in ListView

Tags: vb.net, listview, checkbox

I am trying to programmatically check a checkbox of a `ListView` (using VB & .NET 4).

The ListView `lvVorschlag` has been created in the designer, along with three elements. I then do the following:

```
Dim lviOptimal As New ListViewItem("Optimal")
lviOptimal.SubItems.Add(...) 'several SubItems are added
lvVorschlag.Items.Add(lviOptimal)
lvVorschlag.Items(0).Selected = True
```

All the SubItems are correctly added and the line `lvVorschlag.Items(0).Selected = True` does not give me an error. But nothing is checked. Any idea why?

Note: I also tried with `lvVorschlag.Items("Optimal").Selected = True` but it gives me an error saying that this object is `Nothing`. Too bad, referring by name would have been easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the `Checked` property to check the item(s) you'd like:

```
lvVorschlag.Items(0).Checked = True
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the focus on the item

```
Dim lviOptimal As New ListViewItem("Optimal")
lviOptimal.SubItems.Add(...) 'several SubItems are added
lvVorschlag.Items.Add(lviOptimal)
lvVorschlag.Items(0).focus()
lvVorschlag.Items(0).Selected = True
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4x56c0b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the hint on selecting items. This is not what I was looking for though: I wanted to check a checkbox.